# How to reduce scale in python decimal value

Tags: python, decimal

I have a Decimal value as `Decimal('3.10E-7')`. How to convert it to `Decimal('3.1E-7)`?

I have some function (which I don't have control over) which is returning me the first value. And I am trying to write the returned value using fastavro with precision as 20 and scale as 8. For this particular value I am getting the error

> ValueError: Scale provided in schema does not match the decimal

as the scale is 9.

```
>>> Decimal('3.10E-7').as_tuple()
DecimalTuple(sign=0, digits=(3, 1, 0), exponent=-9)
>>> Decimal('3.1E-7').as_tuple()
DecimalTuple(sign=0, digits=(3, 1), exponent=-8)
```

How do we convert `Decimal('3.10E-7')` to `Decimal('3.1E-7)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Decimal.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.normalize) seems to do what you are asking for:

> Normalize the number by stripping the rightmost trailing zeros [...]

Calling `Decimal('3.10E-7').normalize()` returns `Decimal('3.1E-7')`.

Comment: You also might have to add some rounding if you had e.g. `3.11E-7`.