# How to normalize decimal values while iterating over dataframe rows using toLocalIterator

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, fastavro

I have a pyspark dataframe which contains a decimal column and the schema for that particular decimal column is `Decimal(20,8)`. When I do a `df.show()` it shows `3.1E-7` as value for the decimal column for a particular row.

Now I am trying to write this dataframe streaming to an avro file using fastavro and for that I am iterating over all the rows using `toLocalIterator`. When I get to the row with the above value it is containing `Decimal('3.10E-7')` and this is breaking my avro writer code with below error as this value is resulting the scale as 9 but my avro file is expecting scale as 8

```
ValueError: Scale provided in schema does not match the decimal
```

I was able to iterate over each field for every row and wherever it is decimal datatype, I am using `normalize` method over it and then passing it to the avro writer (Ref: [How to reduce scale in python decimal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71698078/how-to-reduce-scale-in-python-decimal-value)). This makes the code slower and inefficient I believe. Is there any other better way?